# Problems with \parskip

Tags: spacing, parskip, parindent

I have some problems with the usage of the `\parskip` package. For me it seems to have no effect on my document. I am using `\usepackage{parskip}` but there is no space between two paragraphs. If I do this for example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}
some text

some text\par
some text\\
some text
\end{document}
```

the output will be four identical lines with no space between.
I also tried to use the package as `\usepackage[indent]{parskip}` what should result in an indent at every new paragraph, but it also has no effect to the document. Are there any further options I don't used or any problems with some other packages?

The option `\par\smallskip` works exactly how it should in the whole document.

Answer (score 2):

There is additional space between paragraphs in your example

[image]

Note the first two spaces are bigger than than the third.

What is true is that `setspace` package does not scale parskip by the same factor as it scales baselineskip, so if you increase the baseline spacing  the paragraph spacing stays the same and is visually less noticeable.

Code to scale \parskip is in the package but not active in latex2e.

If you use `\usepackage[indent]{parskip}` in your example, then you get

[image]

showing indented paragraphs, with just the last line of the final two-line paragraph being set flush to the left margin. You say this did not work but you do not show the output you got?

Answer (score 0):

There *is* more space with `\usepackage{parskip}` or `\usepackage[indent]{parskip}`—presumably, you didn't look closely enough. Here is a side by side comparison of this on the left:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\raggedbottom won't change anything for a single page
\usepackage[indent]{parskip}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}
some text

some text\par
some text\\
some text
\end{document}
```

and on the right, the same with the `\usepackage[indent]{parskip}` line commented out:

[image]

Comment: well, I tried to make a minimal. Obviousely it didn't work. I tried these two things in a plain document and there it worked, but in my final document it didn't. Thats why I'm asking if there may be some incompatibilities with other packages or things like that. Seems like my question wasn't that exact.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem: I used a `\raggedright` at the beginning of the document what seems to prevent the indent and also the space between paragraphs. When I remove the `\raggedright` and use a `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` in replacement for `\centering` there are no more problems.

Comment: this is barely an answer to the question as posted as that does not mention `\raggedright` Please _always_ make sure the example in the question is an example of the problem that you are asking about. In the scope of `\raggedright` (and `\centering`) `\\ ` forces an end of paragraph so you see the additional `\parskip` space in all cases. If you extended the text so you got a natural linebreak you would see the smaller `\baselineskip` space even there.

Comment: I'm very sorry about this. I had no clue where my problem is. This is why I asked about problems according other packages or things like that I missed. Unfortunately my question wasn't clear about that.

Comment: no harm done, but it just shows why we almost always ask people to include examples in the question that demonstrate the error. If you had tested your example before posting the question you would have seen that it didn't match the problem description, and saved people trying to answer from being misled about the actual issue.